# Get the followers count for Twitter users

Tags: twitter

I had an academic API with Twitter until they completely removed this on June 25, 2023. My research project is agonizingly close to having all the necessary data, but it needs the followers count for a high number of users (4,000,000).

Is there any imaginable way I could get access to this data now? I am fine with paying a reasonable fee, but the only option besides the laughable Pro API is the Basic plan at $100 a month which has abysmal rate limits (I could get maybe 50,000 users per day at best).

Their documentation is extremely unclear as to what is possible with the API 1.1, or how to connect to it for the use I want. They give the following code:

curl --request GET --url 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id=783214,6253282' --header 'authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="CONSUMER_API_KEY", oauth_nonce="OAUTH_NONCE", oauth_signature="OAUTH_SIGNATURE", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="OAUTH_TIMESTAMP", oauth_token="ACCESS_TOKEN", oauth_version="1.0"'

However, I keep getting "215 Bad Authentication data" no matter what I put for the parameters.

Any suggestions, or am I basically SOL as long as current Twitter management remains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [1.1 Rate Limit Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/rate-limits), calls to GET followers/ids are limited to 15 requests per 15 minute window (or 1,440 per day).

In order to access this endpoint, you'll need to implement OAuth as per the [Twitter OAuth documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0).

The [Getting Started](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api) page suggests that you'll need the $5,000 tier to satisfy the four-million-request requirement in a reasonable amount of time.